# How do I look at a file across revisions?

Tags: tig

I'm familiar with using https://github.com/jonas/tig to view my changes, but often I want to see the whole file and quickly run through the changes. I think this "git timemachine" feature doesn't exist in `tig` judging my these bug reports:

- https://github.com/jonas/tig/issues/1006
- https://github.com/jonas/tig/issues/450

My workaround is the use `tig blame $filename` and hit `f` to look at the blob at that revision, which is super awkward since different lines change at different times.

What am I missing?

Comment: My workaround is to use :0Gclog from vim-fugitive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this binding:

```
bind generic V !sh -c 'git show $1:$2' -- %(commit) %(fileargs)
```

then run something like `tig -- README.adoc`.
Select a commit and hit "V" to view the file.

Comment: sorry, what key is "ae"?

Comment: Doesn't work, just gives me a file listing? https://s.natalian.org/2021-12-01/tig-try.mp4

Comment: "ae" is just a sequence of two keys.

Comment: My bad, `%(file)` is only filled after you move your cursor over a file in diff view etc.
But instead you can use `%(fileargs)`, that will use whatever you passed on the command line (RADME.adoc in this case)